# Scraping a javascript response through beautifulsoup, possible?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests-html

The server returns the below response, it is apparantly javascript contents and I wanted to scrape it but I am unable to do it.

**Element.update("to_users2", "\n\n\n<div class="label-field-pair">\n  <div class="label-field-pair11">\n    <label for="student_grade">Select member\n    <div class ="scrolable" >\n      <div class="scroll-inside">\n        <div class="hover"><a href="#" class="all" onClick="add_all_recipient('2,4')">Select all   Add \n\n        \n        \n          \n          <div class="hover"><a href="#" before="Element.show('loader')" class="individual" onClick="add_recipient(2)" success="Element.hide('loader')">TestUserOne  Add \n\n          \n        \n          \n          <div class="hover"><a href="#" before="Element.show('loader')" class="individual" onClick="add_recipient(4)" success="Element.hide('loader')">TestUserTwo  Add \n\n          \n        \n      \n    \n  \n\n\n\n");**

Basically, I tried a number of possibilities like converting the response object into string and then replacing all `\n` and so on and then using the resulting `html` I also tried to use `requests_html` which nearly given me the expecting result but still not able to get the expected result. I expected to scrape the `add_recipient(2)` in the `a` tag and the `a` tag text `TestUserOne` in this case. in `requests_html`, I can do something like:

```
htm = '''Element.update("to_users2", "\n\n\n<div class="label-field-pair">\n <div class="label-field-pair11">\n <label for="student_grade">Select member\n <div class ="scrolable" >\n <div class="scroll-inside">\n <div class="hover"><a href="#" class="all" onClick="add_all_recipient('2,4')">Select all Add \n\n \n \n \n <div class="hover"><a href="#" before="Element.show('loader')" class="individual" onClick="add_recipient(2)" success="Element.hide('loader')">TestUserOne Add \n\n \n \n \n <div class="hover"><a href="#" before="Element.show('loader')" class="individual" onClick="add_recipient(4)" success="Element.hide('loader')">TestUserTwo Add \n\n \n \n \n \n \n\n\n\n");'''

html = HTML(html=htm)
print(html.find('a'))
```

and it gives the output

```
<Element 'a' href='\\"#\\"' before='\\"Element.show(\'loader\')\\"' class=('\\"individual\\"',) onclick='\\"add_recipient(4)\\"' success='\\"Element.hide(\'loader\')\\"'>,
```

Here I wanted to scrape the `onclick` value and hence get the `a` tag text like `TestUserOne Add` in this context.

where to from here? tried all possibilities but nothing avail. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to parse JavaScript values such as that using BeautifulSoup. One solution could be to use a regular expression:

**main.py**

```py
import re

resp = """
Element.update("to_users2", "\n\n\n<div class="label-field-pair">\n <div class="label-field-pair11">\n <label for="student_grade">Select member\n <div class ="scrolable" >\n <div class="scroll-inside">\n <div class="hover"><a href="#" class="all" onClick="add_all_recipient('2,4')">Select all Add \n\n \n \n \n <div class="hover"><a href="#" before="Element.show('loader')" class="individual" onClick="add_recipient(2)" success="Element.hide('loader')">TestUserOne Add \n\n \n \n \n <div class="hover"><a href="#" before="Element.show('loader')" class="individual" onClick="add_recipient(4)" success="Element.hide('loader')">TestUserTwo Add \n\n \n \n \n \n \n\n\n\n");
"""

print(re.findall(r"add_recipient\(([0-9+])\)\" success=.+>([a-zA-Z0-9\w]+) Add", resp))
```

```sh
$ python main.py
[('2', 'TestUserOne'), ('4', 'TestUserTwo')]
```

Comment: following this: I get this error when passed response from the server `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Comment: That's because `find()` will return a `BeautifulSoup.Tag` object. Cast it to a string before trying to use it in a regular expression.

Comment: well using `str(res)`, casting it to string yields`[]`

Comment: What exactly is `res`? A requests response object? It's not in your main post. Nobody can help you without any context as to what you're actually doing.

Comment: `res = requests.post(req_url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data)` because it is sensitive I can't disclose all code but in the code you posted works fine but when replaced the `re.findall(r"add_recipient\(([0-9+])\)\" success=.+>([a-zA-Z0-9\w]+) Add", resp)` with `re.findall(r"add_recipient\(([0-9+])\)\" success=.+>([a-zA-Z0-9\w]+) Add", str(res))` nothing appears only `[]`

Comment: Okay - that's because Requests doesn't return a string. It returns a `requests.Response` object. Replace `res` with `res.text`.

Comment: I did this: `regexp = re.findall(r"add_recipient\(([0-9+])\)\" success=.+>([a-zA-Z0-9\w]+) Add", str(res.text))

        print(regexp)` but getting same result `[]`

Comment: Time for some debugging - does `res.text` actually contain the text you're looking for? Are you sure the request is behaving as expected?

Comment: Yeah I can confirm that the `res.text` is displaying expected response.

Comment: what you think this?